# Build mozilla JSS

Tags: mozilla, nss

I followed NSS [build instructions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/Reference/Building_and_installing_NSS) and built NSS successfully.
Then I follow [JSS build instructions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/JSS/Build_instructions_for_JSS_4.3.x) and building fails with error:

```
In file included from CryptoManager.c:6:0:
../../../../dist/public/nss/secitem.h:15:21: fatal error: plarena.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

This result is on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

On WIndows I get:

[image]

All directories (dist, jss, nspr and nss) are on the same level.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check my post [here](https://www.zybuluo.com/torresdyl/note/5634620). Basically it's due to missing packages. If not working, this file is somewhere under `nspr`. Copy it and place it beside the `.c` file which needs it.

EDIT:

To sum it up:

#### 1. Install `build-essential` and `gcc` with `g++`.

#### 2. Try to install `zlib1g-dev` and `libc6-dev`, if they are absent.

#### 3. And, install `zlib1g-dev`.

#### 4. `cd` into the `nss` directory, and run the build like this:

```
gmake nss_build_all NSS_SSL_ENABLE_ZLIB=
```

if you are under a x64 environment, add `USE_64=1`, too.

It should work.